# Servlet.init() for servlet spring-dispatcher threw exception 3

Tags: java, spring-mvc, servlets, pom.xml

```
Web.xml

    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" 
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" 
    id="WebApp_ID" 
    version="3.0">
      <display-name>Project</display-name>

      <servlet>
        <servlet-name>spring-dispatcher</servlet-name>
          <servlet-class>
              org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
          </servlet-class>
      </servlet>
      <servlet-mapping>
          <servlet-name>spring-dispatcher</servlet-name>
          <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
      </servlet-mapping>
      </web-app>
```

This is my  spring-dispatcher-servlet.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<beans xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XML-Schema-instance"
       xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc 
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd"> 

       <context:component-scan base-package="com.sample" />


       <bean id="viewResolver
       class=org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
         <property name="prefix">
         <value>/WEB-INF/</value>
         </property>
         <property name="suffix">
         <value>.jsp</value>
         </property>
       </bean>
</beans>
```

This is my controller  HelloController.java

```
    package com.sample;

    import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
    import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
    import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;

    @Controller
    public class HelloController {

            @RequestMapping("/welcome")
        public ModelAndView helloWorld(){

                ModelAndView model = new ModelAndView("Hellopage");
                model.addObject("message","welcome page");

                return model;

            }
    }
```

This is my JSP page Hellopage.jsp

```
    <html>
    <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
    <title>Insert title here</title>
    </head>
    <body>
      <h1>${message}</h1>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Exception

type Exception report

message Servlet.init() for servlet spring-dispatcher threw exception

description The server encountered an internal error that prevented it from fulfilling this request.

exception

```
javax.servlet.ServletException: Servlet.init() for servlet spring-dispatcher threw exception
    org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:505)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:956)
    org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:436)
    org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1078)
    org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:625)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:316)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)



root cause 
org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionStoreException: Line 13 in XML document from ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/spring-dispatcher-servlet.xml] is invalid; nested exception is org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 13; columnNumber: 67; cvc-elt.1: Cannot find the declaration of element 'beans'.
    org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.doLoadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:398)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:335)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:303)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:180)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:216)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:187)
    org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlWebApplicationContext.java:125)
    org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlWebApplicationContext.java:94)
    org.springframework.context.support.AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.refreshBeanFactory(AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.java:129)
    org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.obtainFreshBeanFactory(AbstractApplicationContext.java:540)
    org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:454)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:658)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:624)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:672)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:543)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initServletBean(FrameworkServlet.java:484)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.init(HttpServletBean.java:136)
    javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:158)
    org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:505)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:956)
    org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:436)
    org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1078)
    org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:625)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:316)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)



root cause 
org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 13; columnNumber: 67; cvc-elt.1: Cannot find the declaration of element 'beans'.
    com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.createSAXParseException(Unknown Source)
    com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.error(Unknown Source)
    com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(Unknown Source)
    com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(Unknown Source
```

Answer (score 0):

Try like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<beans xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XML-Schema-instance"
       xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc 
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd"> 

       <context:component-scan base-package="com.sample" />


       <beans:bean id="viewResolver
       class=org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
         <beans:property name="prefix">
         <beans:value>/WEB-INF/</beans:value>
         </beans:property>
         <beans:property name="suffix">
         <beans:value>.jsp</beans:value>
         </beans:property>
       </beans:bean>
</beans:beans>
```

You are declaring the `"http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"` schema as  `xmlns:beans`, so you must use `beans:` prefix before any beans' schema element

EDIT

You also miss a trailing `"` after the id attribute in the `<beans:bean id="viewResolver`, and the opening `"` before the class attribute in the same element `class=org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver"`

```
    <beans:bean id="viewResolver" 
class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <beans:property name="prefix">
          <beans:value>/WEB-INF/</beans:value>
        </beans:property>
        <beans:property name="suffix">
          <beans:value>.jsp</beans:value>
        </beans:property>
     </beans:bean>
```

Comment: Have a look at my last edit please. You miss `"` in some places